# Prolog: Palindrome predicate never succeeds

Tags: prolog, palindrome

I developed a palindrome checking algorithm that simply reverses a given list of elements; using naive reversing. The program then checks if it yields the same list or not. But I seem to have a problem that I can't figure out. The program always return false. Here's the program I've developed so far...

```
reverseCurrentList([H|T],ReversedList):-
    reverseCurrentList(T,RevT),
    append(RevT,[H],ReversedList).

isPalindrome(GivenList):- 
    reverseCurrentList(GivenList,ReversedList),
    GivenList=@=ReversedList.
```

---

#### Edit: final version

In the end, I settled with the following code:

```
% A palindrome can be read forward or backward; e.g. [x,a,m,a,x]

% is_palindrome(L) :- L is a palindrome list

is_palindrome(L) :-
   reverse(L,L).
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this question. Initially you had a custom predicate for palindrome which wasn't working because it was missing a base case that @dasblinkenlight pointed out in his answer, and you accepted the answer. Then you edited your problem with a different implementation, using `reverse`, which works fine.

Comment: @lurker I slipped up sir, sorry. It's now corrected.

Comment: @repeat It should be reverted to be useful, I think. As it stands, it really doesn't make sense.

Comment: Put both versions in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `reverseCurrentList` rule is missing a base clause, so it never succeeds. The recursive invocation continues taking items from the list until the list is empty, at which point `[H|T]` no longer unifies, so the rule fails.

Add this second clause to your program:

```
reverseCurrentList([], []).
```

Comment: Thanks so much sir, It now works. But can I please ask what does this base clause mean? does it mean that the reversing stops when the 2 lists are empty? If so, then how come the program checks if the 2 lists are equal after?

Comment: @user3490561 The recursive clause that you wrote reverses the list by appending the head to the result of reversing its tail, i.e. by reversing a list that is shorter by one item. At some point, the tail has no items. This is when the base clause comes into play: it tells your program how to solve the "degenerate case", i.e. how to reverse an empty list. Once this goal is reached, your program stops reversing, and starts appending list heads to recursively constructed reversed lists.

Comment: Thanks so much sir for your precise and informative answer.

Comment: Note that `isPalindrome([A,B])` fails but should rather suceed unifying `A` with `B`.